# How to do I make a 5D List

Tags: list

I want to know how I would go about making a 5D list in python? I've tried googling but I haven't found any relevant topics on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use layers of square brackets, like this:

```
5D = [[[[[]]]]]
```